# Possible error in 'Quaternions' tutorial

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried transforming roll, pitch, yaw angles to a quaternion in python following this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions). In subtopic 3 "Think in RPY then convert to quaternion" the import statement is `from tf_conversions.transformations import quaternion_from_euler`. When trying to run my node python said that it can't find the module tf_conversions.transformations. I tried many things and finally looked into the source code of the package. Turns out that the import has to be `from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler`, because the `quaternion_from_euler` function is located in this file: https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/noetic-devel/tf/src/tf/transformations.py.

I am not sure how to correct the tutorial page but maybe this help somebody to change it or at least get the import right. I was struggling with this for 2 straight hours thinking the tutorial was right...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378765/possible-error-in-%27quaternions%27-tutorial/) by [sdoering](https://answers.ros.org/users/74896/sdoering/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-05-21**:
Please correct it! I think you just need to click the Login button then make an account.

**Comment by [sdoering](https://answers.ros.org/users/74896/sdoering/) on 2021-05-22**:
I requested access to edit the ROS wiki and will correct to article once I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I was struggling with this for 2 straight hours thinking the tutorial was right

I know you are completely true.

From next time follow these links for documentation for the enhancement document.
http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/tf/html/python/

http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/

Over here you can get a list of all packages that are launched with particular distribution and their functions.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0